# Javascript bookmarklet doesn't change an image's source

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I've been attempting for a little while now to create a bookmarklet that simply replaces all the website's images with a single other one. After trying, and trying some more, I got a line of code that *should* work, but it just... doesn't.

```
javascript:function img_find() {var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");return imgs;}  var images = img_find(); for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {images[i].src.replace(images[i].src, "https://api.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/caveman-spongebob-spongegar.png";}
```

That's some code I've tried. I also tried:

```
javascript:function img_find() {var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");return imgs;}  var images = img_find(); for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {images[i].src = "https://api.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/caveman-spongebob-spongegar.png";}
```

Both pieces of code don't work for some reason, the first not doing anything and the second just replacing the entire webpage with the url.

Comment: Could you explain a little more what's happen? Because I see nothing is wrong in your second line, just to pick one.

Answer (score 0):

As told in the comment your second snippet just works as expected, as for the first snippets, it doesn't work because the replace method doesn't change the original string passed to it, but return instead a new replaced one. In other words in the first snippet you should write inside the the for cycle:

```
images[i].src = images[i].src.replace(images[i].src, "https://api.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/caveman-spongebob-spongegar.png");
```

in place of your:

```
images[i].src.replace(images[i].src, "https://api.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/caveman-spongebob-spongegar.png");
```

That said I would anyway use the second snippet, the first one it's like using a drill to puncture a sheet of paper.

**First Snippet**

```js
function img_find() {
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  return imgs;
}

var images = img_find();

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  
  images[i].src = images[i].src.replace(images[i].src, "https://api.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/caveman-spongebob-spongegar.png");
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="150">
</div>
```

**Second Snippet**

```js
function img_find() {
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");
  return imgs;
}

var images = img_find();

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  
  images[i].src = "https://api.time.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/caveman-spongebob-spongegar.png";
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="150">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="150">
</div>
```

Comment: [link](https://lh3.google.com/u/1/d/13kXPKMvWaioEDioh_mY6TJJe67h3hgiF=w1366-h625-iv1) Here's a link to what ends up happening. When used as a bookmarklet, for both snippets of codes, it replaces any webpage with this. This was google.com, by the way.

Comment: @Lionmeow I'm sorry but I'm not quite sure to understand what you're writing. If any of the previous snippets replace any content on the page with the link you've provided there's something strange on your machine.